# How to store files in azure table using form from react?

Tags: azure

I want to store user files like pdf, doc, and image from user interface using React. How can i store these types of files in azure table?

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should not store binary data in Azure Tables. Use Blob Storage instead.

Comment: I am using an application where users are filling in all the details like name, address, and some proof such as pdf file and image or doc, that's why I am thinking of this. Is there any solution to this? @GauravMantri

Comment: You would need to use multiple data stores in this case. You can use blob storage for storing images/documents etc. and table storage for other things.